# Using 0 as default count value

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server

I have a query (portion of it) like this below, when my GridView is loaded with this query, those rows that has got no value for `IssCount` and `UsedCount` will be blank. How can I set a default `0` value for these columns for such records?

```
SELECT
    CASE
    WHEN @SortByTypeCode = 1 THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY vt.Code)
    WHEN @SortByTypeName = 1 THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY vt.Name)               
    WHEN @SortByTypeIssued = 1 THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY count(X.IssCount))
    WHEN @SortByTypeUsed = 1 THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY count(Y.UsedCount ))
    ELSE ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY vt.AutoID)
    END AS RowNum
    ,vt.AutoID
    ,vt.Code
    ,X.IssCount as Issued
    ,Y.UsedCount as Used
INTO #tmp_Results --Dont Change This
FROM VoucherType vt
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT VoucherType_AutoID,COUNT(VoucherNo) IssCount
    FROM Voucher
    WHERE VoidedBy IS NULL AND VoidedOn IS NULL 
    GROUP BY VoucherType_AutoID     
) X ON vt.AutoID = X.VoucherType_AutoID
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT V.VoucherType_AutoID, COUNT(VUsed.AutoID) UsedCount
    FROM voucherUsedLog VUsed
    INNER JOIN Voucher V ON VUsed.Voucher_AutoID = V.AutoID
    WHERE VUsed.VoidedBy IS NULL AND VUsed.VoidedOn IS NULL
    GROUP BY V.VoucherType_AutoID
) Y
ON vt.AutoID = Y.VoucherType_AutoID
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just wrap a `COALESCE` around `X.IssCount` and `Y.UsedCount` to make them 0, like so:

```
,COALESCE(X.IssCount,0) as Issued
,COALESCE(Y.UsedCount,0) as Used
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this way..

```
ISNULL(X.IssCount,0) as Issued
,ISNULL(Y.UsedCount,0) as Used
```